# Huge drop in Google Analytics after site update

Tags: google-analytics

I released a new version of my website today and with the old version, I was around 90 visitors an hour, and after the update, it dropped to around 20 visitors.

I don't know what went wrong. Here's the stats:

[image: Huge drop between 15:00 and 16:00]

As you can see, a drop occurred between 3pm and 4pm and drop to finally get to 0 since then.

I added an httpS connection, but the non www and http all redirects to `https://www` automatically. The tracker is the same, I only added

```
ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
ga('set', 'appVersion', '2');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

There is only one page (it's a basic app), so there is no other page that could have the tracker removed.

Now, I'm wondering something, when I start the tracker, I send this info :

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'voilanorbert.com');
```

shouldn't it be `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'www.voilanorbert.com');`? (with "www.") Is this the issue?

**Big Update**: I decided to create a new tracker in Google to see if this was a reason, and **yes it is**! A few minutes after I changed it to the new tracker, the data went to 1 visitors per hour, to 18 in real time! There is clearly a problem in Google Analytics!

Comment: The third parameter in the 'create' method sets the cookie domain, so I don't think it should affect the number of site visits. If you  use domain.com, then the cookie is set to the track across domain.com as well as subdomains, including www. By default, if you left out that parameter, then the cookie domain would be set to "auto", which has the same effect as setting that parameter to "domain.com".

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried to switch it to 'auto', but since then, I'm now at 0. It's impossible that I went from 90 visitors per hour to 0, at the same time of the release. Something must be wrong, but I don't know what :/

Comment: Just as a best practice, can you move the tracking snippet to be within the <head> tags? I currently see it in the <body>.

Comment: I pushed the update with the tracker in the head :)

Comment: Cool, at least now Google Tag Assistant is happy. :) Are you able to see activity in your Real-time reports?

Comment: Yes, I can see peoples, but they are now 1/2, instead of 5/6. I updated an other website a few years ago and had the same drop in visitors (from 1000 daily to 150). I'm pretty sure it's not the real visitors, but can't explain the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tracking code was flawed. This does not imply Google Analytics does not work.

- The appVersion parameter is reserved for mobile apps and not for the web collection API.
- forceSSL is kind of obsolete now

When in doubt, stick to the regular tracking code or use Google Tag Manager.